# Make changes to a .bat file using python

Tags: python, batch-file, command

I want to make changes to a bat file using python and save it, so that I can call it later.

For example,
I have read.bat. It contains an address to a folder.

I run it.

Then I make a change to the address.

Then I run it again.

How can I do this using python. So far I was only able to create new bat files, but I am unable to edit the existing one and save it.

Comment: Read the contents of the file into a `list` of `str`, each `str` is a line. Make the changes you wish to the lines. Then write the lines to the file. You can't insert things into the middle of the file, you have to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Save if I rewrite the whole thing and save it with the same name, would the file be rewritten?? Or would it be a new file with a different name?

Comment: If you are changing the same string in the batch file, over and over again, wouldn't it make more sense to make that string a variable, which reflects an input parameter? and feed that input as either a typed argument at run time? by input request in the batch-file itself? or from each line read from a file? etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just edit one line in the .bat file you can try this:

```
with open("path/to/file.bat", "rt") as bat_file:
    text = bat_file.readlines()

new_text = []
for line in text:
    if "address/you/want/to/change" in line:
        new_text.append(line.replace("address/you/want/to/change", "new/address/line"))
    else:
        new_text.append(line)

with open("path/to/file.bat", "wt") as bat_file:
    for line in new_text:
        bat_file.write(line)
```

What it's doing is reading all the lines of the current `.bat` file, then looping through the lines and changing the one you want to change to whatever you want to change it to.

After that, the file is opened again in write mode so all the lines can be written to the `.bat` file (updating the text).